# .htaccess file and linux server

Tags: asp.net, .htaccess

Do `.htaccess` files only work on Linux servers? I am working in `ASP.Net`.

If it doesn't work with ASP, then what is the alternative solution?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Pekka i m trying to apply "301 Moved Permanently" in asp.net.I want to check it in local host but I am unable to do.Any idea plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET production deployment happens over IIS (web server from MS) - IIS has its own authorization mechanism. See this link for translating htaccess into equivalent IIS configuration: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/557/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig/

Alternately, you can also use commercial products such as [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/) that provides IIS Add-on that will support Apache .htacces and .htpasswd files.

Comment: VinayC@ i m trying to apply "301 Moved Permanently" in asp.net.I want to check it in local host but I am unable to do.Any idea plz help.

Comment: @Shree, see IIS section in http://knowledge.freshpromo.ca/seo-tools/301-redirect.php